# AnalysisException: Sparksql - SUM with CASE WHEN

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, aggregate

I am using following query for my data.

```
  df_xl.createOrReplaceTempView('df_xl')
    df_ct = spark.sql("""
    SELECT SERIES,
           Sum(CASE WHEN CHANNEL IN ('BXV','Comedy Central','ZV') THEN (COUNT(ID)) ELSE 0
           END) AS `M0-05`
    FROM df_xl 
    GROUP BY SERIES
    """)
```

snowflake query

```
Step1 :: CASE WHEN CHANNEL IN  ('BXV','Comedy Central','ZV') THEN COUNT(ID) ELSE 0 END AS "M0-05"

Step2 :: SUM("M0-05") AS "M0-05"
```

example output

```
    SERIES       M0-05  
0   ABC          11546
1   GHQ          883    
2   SA           5036   
3   STAR         762
```

However, I was not able to run `sum` and `case when` and `in` together. This query goes OK without sum.

```
AnalysisException: It is not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function. Please use the inner aggregate function in a sub-query.;;
```

Could any one please suggest/guide?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `COUNT()` in a `SUM()`.  I think you want:

```
SELECT SERIES,
       Sum(CASE WHEN CHANNEL IN ('BXV','Comedy Central','ZV') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `M0-05`
FROM df_xl 
GROUP BY SERIES
```